# C++ Nested Loop dynamic array size

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, clr

I'm trying create a method that returns the sum of all values in an array list. I'm getting an error on this line `sum+= setItem[x][y][z];`  The error is

```
 expression must have pointer-to-object or handle-to-CLI-array type c:\Development\Source\Source\Source.cpp
```

full function

```
int getTotal(ArrayList^ set)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for each (Array^ setItem in set)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x< 3; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < setItem->Length; y++){
                for(int z = 0; z< setItem->Length; z++)
                {
                    sum+= setItem[x][y][z];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `setItem` is multidimensional array, you need a different syntax:  Try: `sum+= setItem[x,y,z];`

Comment: it still gives that error it also say 'default': is not a member of 'System::Array'

Comment: can you update your question with how the `ArrayList` (i.e. `set`) is populated and how those `Array` objects are created?

Comment: What if you changed the type of `setItem` to `array<int, 3>^`? (note lowercase `array`)